# User input as global variable to display text from different views

Tags: swift, macos, global-variables, swift3, user-input

I have a main View Controller than has a "Sign In" button if a user is not logged in.  I then have another view controller "Login View Controller" that checks if user exists and then logs them in.  Once a user has logged in via the login View Controller.  I want the text of my Sign In Button on my main view controller to change to their email that they used to login.  I am using a struct to try and accomplish this.  My struct email variable seems to work within my Login View Controller but then does not change the string value of my button on the main view controller.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
class LoginViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: NSTextField!


struct GloablUserEmail {

    static var user_status = Bool()
    static var user_email  = String()

}

@IBAction func LoginPushed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    GloablUserEmail.user_email = userEmailTextField.stringValue

let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "myurl")!

    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "user_email=\(GloablUserEmail.user_email)&user_password=\(user_password)"
    urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {

            do{

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {

                    let resultValue = parseJSON["Status"] as? String
                    print("result: \(resultValue)")

                    self.isUserRegistered = false

                    if(resultValue=="Success"){

                        GloablUserEmail.user_status = true;

                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();

                    }
                }

            }catch{

                print("Error parsing the JSON: \(error)")

            }
        }
    }


    task.resume()
    }
}
```

Once the result is successful and the user is verified to exist then I assign the global user_status to true.

**MainViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var SignInButton: NSButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    if(LoginViewController.GloablUserEmail.user_status == false){

        SignInButton.title = "Sign In"

    }else if(LoginViewController.GloablUserEmail.user_status == true){

        SignInButton.title = LoginViewController.GloablUserEmail.user_email
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Globals make kittens cry.

Comment: Is there an alternative that doesn't make kittens cry?

Comment: Yes, have a well architected design consisting of a reasonable graph of view controllers communicating in a sane way. Unfortunately, it's not always simple and it's not always easy to explain. There are whole books on software design that cover just this. You're using globals as a dodgy way of communicating information across view controllers. There's no reason why the view controllers can't just communicate directly, without the global variable as an intermediary

Answer (score 0):

You can user a simple **UserDefaults** extension:

```
extension UserDefaults{

    var isLoggedIn: Bool{
        return bool(forKey: "loggedIn")
    }

    func set(loggedIn value: Bool){
        set(value, forKey: "loggedIn")
        synchronize()
    }
}
```

To set login status:

```
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
 defaults.set(loggedIn: true)
```

And check its value:

```
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
 defaults.isLoggedIn
```

Comment: I see what youre saying but regardless of checking the status with this code, I still need to pass over the users email from one view to the next.